# Error Inserting TimeStamp column in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to add TimeStamp field in my SQLite Table, see my code below:

*myDBClass.java*

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Create Table Name
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER + 
              "(OperatorID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
              " DeviceID TEXT(100)," +
              " EmailID TEXT(100)," +
              " Operator TEXT(100)," +
              " Created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);");

    Log.d("CREATE TABLE","Create Table Successfully.");
}

// Insert Data
public long InsertData(String strDeviceID, String strEmailID, String strEventOperator, String strCreated_at) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     try {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

        ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
        Val.put("DeviceID", strDeviceID);
        Val.put("EmailID", strEmailID);
        Val.put("Operator", strEventOperator);
        Val.put("Created_at", getDateTime());

        long rows = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBER, null, Val);

        db.close();
        return rows; // return rows inserted.

     } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
     }

}

private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
  }


// Select Data
public String[] SelectData(String strOperatorID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     try {
        String arrData[] = null;    

         SQLiteDatabase db;
         db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

         Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMBER, new String[] { "*" }, 
                    "OperatorID=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(strOperatorID) }, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null)
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    arrData = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];
                    /***
                     *  0 = DeviceID
                     *  1 = EmailID
                     *  2 = EventOperator
                     */
                    arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0);
                    arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1);
                    arrData[2] = cursor.getString(2);
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return arrData;

     } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
     }

}
```

*AddActivity.java*

```
public boolean SaveData()
    {       
        final EditText editDeviceID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDeviceID);
        final EditText editEmailID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailID);
        final EditText editEveOpe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEveOpe);       
        // Dialog
        final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog ad = adb.create();

        // new Class DB
        final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);

        // Save Data
        long saveStatus = myDb.InsertData(
                editDeviceID.getText().toString(),
                editEmailID.getText().toString(),
                editEveOpe.getText().toString()
                );
        if(saveStatus <=  0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Error!! ");
            ad.show();
            return false;
        }

         Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this,"Added Data Successfully. ",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

        return true;
    }

}
```

*Log:*

```
12-19 01:39:08.147: E/SQLiteLog(6963): (1) table members has no column named Created_at
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963): Error inserting DeviceID=safdasfewrwesd23432 Created_at=2013-12-19 01:39:08 EventOperator=adsfewvweceEvent EmailID=sdfasdf@desa.cond
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table members has no column named Created_at (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO members(DeviceID,Created_at,EventOperator,EmailID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at com.example.database.myDBClass.InsertData(myDBClass.java:59)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at com.example.database.AddActivity.SaveData(AddActivity.java:49)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at com.example.database.AddActivity$1.onClick(AddActivity.java:26)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-19 01:39:08.203: E/SQLiteDatabase(6963):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 01:39:08.434: D/dalvikvm(6963): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 138K, 7% free 3169K/3384K, paused 28ms, total 38ms
```

I am getting **table members** has no column **named Created_at**

I am little bit confuse what to use for ***Created_at column in Insert Query*** **(AddActivity.java)**

Still in my **members table**, fields are: OperatorID, DeviceID, EmailID, Operator but i am also trying to add **Created_at** field in members table., but facing problem

Comment: Which are your field names in the table of `members`

Comment: @SilentKiller 
Still in my **members table**, fields are: OperatorID, DeviceID, EmailID, Operator but i am also trying to add **Created_at** field in members table., but facing problem

Comment: Drop table and add with all fields

Comment: @SilentKiller yeah but same thing i want to know, what i need to write in insert query to add insert value of Created_at column of SaveData() method.. see once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no datatype like **DATETIME** in sqlite. so just change your code like below:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER + 
              "(OperatorID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
              " DeviceID TEXT(100)," +
              " EmailID TEXT(100)," +
              " Operator TEXT(100)," +
              " Created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp);");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite doesn't support DATETIME type. Instead, you can store your timestamp as Integer(milisecond) or Text.

Answer (score 0):

When you change your database schema e.g. the `CREATE TABLE` in code, you'll have to make sure the same changes are also done to the actual database file.

`SQLiteOpenHelper` will version your database file. It's the version number you pass to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor that tells the current code schema version. When you change your schema, you should increase that version number.

`SQLiteOpenHelper` will call your `onUpgrade()` when the schema version in your code is higher than in the database file. You can either call `ALTER TABLE` and the like to upgrade your database, or just call `DROP TABLE` on the existing tables and call `onCreate()` to create them using the up-to-date schema. In this latter case you lose any data in the database.

Another, simpler way: Instead of increasing the schema version number, just delete the old database file. You can do this by clearing app data via settings -> manage applications. Or just uninstall and reinstall the app. Don't rely on this trick for released versions though, only do it for schema updates during development.